# Create a dynamic select function in Enity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a question for you regarding the creation of a Dynamic select query in Entity Framework.
I already have a dynamic query for the select based on rights etc. But for each table I get 30+ fields that I have to parse via the .GetType().GetProperties().
Its complex and its quite costly in terms of resource due to the amount of data we have.
I have a service that tells me which fields I should select for each table. I would like to find a way to transform that into the query but I can't find something that is really dynamic.
That is **not dynamic but manual**:

```
using (var context = new StackOverflowContext())
{
    var posts = context.Posts
                       .Where(p => p.Tags == "<sql-server>")
                       .Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Title});

    // Do something;
}
```

I need to say, select only those fields but only the fields with this names. 
I have the field list in a list of string but that could be changed.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a .Net Fiddle code (made by msbendtsen) that allows to dynamically select columns (properties).
https://dotnetfiddle.net/3IMR1r
The sample is written for linq to objects but it should work with entity frameworks.

The key section is:

```
internal static IQueryable SelectProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
{
    // get propertyinfo's from original type
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => propertyNames.Contains(p.Name));

    // Create the x => expression
    var lambdaParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    // Create the x.<propertyName>'s
    var propertyExpressions = properties.Select(p => Expression.Property(lambdaParameterExpression, p));

    // Creating anonymous type using dictionary of property name and property type
    var anonymousType = AnonymousTypeUtils.CreateType(properties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.PropertyType));
    var anonymousTypeConstructor = anonymousType.GetConstructors().Single();
    var anonymousTypeMembers = anonymousType.GetProperties().Cast<MemberInfo>().ToArray();

    // Create the new {} expression using 
    var anonymousTypeNewExpression = Expression.New(anonymousTypeConstructor, propertyExpressions, anonymousTypeMembers);

    var selectLambdaMethod = GetExpressionLambdaMethod(lambdaParameterExpression.Type, anonymousType);
    var selectBodyLambdaParameters = new object[] { anonymousTypeNewExpression, new[] { lambdaParameterExpression } };
    var selectBodyLambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)selectLambdaMethod.Invoke(null, selectBodyLambdaParameters);

    var selectMethod = GetQueryableSelectMethod(typeof(T), anonymousType);
    var selectedQueryable = selectMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { queryable, selectBodyLambdaExpression }) as IQueryable;
    return selectedQueryable;
}
```